# why the ng-class not changed?

Tags: angularjs, menu, tabs, switch-statement

Examples of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/paloalto/DTXC2/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div id="wrapper" ng-controller="AppController" ng-class="showChatPanel">

        <div id="tabBar" class="ui vertical icon menu inverted" ng-controller="TabBarController">
            <a class="item switchChatBtn" data-tab="showChatWraper">Open Chat Panel</a>
        </div>

        <div id="chatWraper" class="ui segment">Chat Panel Opend!!</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.controllers']);

var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers', []);

controllers.controller('AppController', function AppController($scope, $log, $http) {

    $scope.showChatPanel = '';

    $scope.$on("switchChatPanel", function (event, msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        $scope.showChatPanel = msg;
        console.log($scope.showChatPanel);
        // $scope.$broadcast("switchChatPanel-done", msg);
    });

    $scope.$watch('showChatPanel', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal){
            console.log('yeah! It is a newVal !!!');
        } else {
            console.log('still oldVal ');
        }
    });
});

controllers.controller('TabBarController', function TabBarController($scope, $log, $http) {
    var tabBarItem =$('#tabBar > .item');
    tabBarItem.click(function(){
        var tabClass = $(this).data('tab');
        console.log(tabClass);
        $scope.$emit("switchChatPanel", tabClass);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#chatWraper {
    display:none;
}

.showChatWraper #chatWraper{
    display:block;
}
```

=====

I finally solved it using jQuery, but I still wonder why angular not success.

```
controllers.controller('TabBarController',function TabBarController ($scope,$log,$http) {

    var tabBarItem =$('#tabBar > .item');
    var chatPanelOpen = false;

    tabBarItem.click(function(){
        var tabClass = $(this).data('tab');

        if(!chatPanelOpen){
            $('#wrapper').addClass(tabClass);
            chatPanelOpen = true;
        } else{
            $('#wrapper').removeClass(tabClass);
            chatPanelOpen = false;
        }
    })
})
```

https://gist.github.com/naoyeye/7695067

========

## UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/paloalto/DTXC2/17/

Comment: I think you need to spend some time in the documentation. You shouldn't be doing any DOM manipulation (ie. jQuery stuff) in your controllers. Have a look at ng-click and ng-class directives as a starting point.

Comment: should definitely read this:  [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: take jquery script tag out of your app while learning angular...will force you to learn how to do things angular way. WIll find you rarely need any jQuery

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be doing DOM manipulation like that in the controller. The correct way to do this is like this

```
<div ng-controller="TabBarController">
    <div ng-click="toggleChatPanel()" ng-class="{tabClass: isChatPanelOpen}">
</div>

controllers.controller('TabBarController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.isChatPanelOpen = false;

   $scope.toggleChatPanel = function () {
     $scope.isChatPanelOpen = !$scope.isChatPanelOpen;
   };
});
```

Comment: now I can add the ".active" class to the tab which be clicked, how to add the ".showChatWraper" class to the parent element? ( The parent element is in another Controller)  Because I use CSS to switch the panel show/hide like this:

`#xxx{display:none;}
.showChatWraper #xxx{display:block;}`

Comment: great - looks good. I'm not sure if I'd use emit there, instead I'd probably create a service that manages all of my information about the chat panel.